# How to find a String that contains Specific other String?

Tags: python, string

I have a problem with my homework and it's just confusing for me, this is the problem:

So input is a string that is a linear Equation Like " A + B = C ". 
but for some reason one of A, B or C is not clear to us and we can't see it right.

for example:

```
"1# + 24  = 34" or "5131 + #251 = 76382"
```

Note that: It can happen to One part of Equation; A, B or C! and '#' can be more than one Digit!

```py
(((( if input is = "10# + 50 = 10052" , output shoul be "10002 + 50 = 10052"))))
```

So here is a Question! How can I Highlight or Select part of this String that contains '#'?

I tried to search in RegExr and I can't find a pattern that matches my situation!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. What do you mean by "Highlight or Select part of this String that contains '#'"? Do you mean "return the index of the '#' character in the string"? And is that your full question, or are you asking for other help on your homework?

Comment: I'm pretty sure I have quite recently seen a question (and answer) about this exact programming problem here on Stack Overflow. The "some reason" was then described as an ink stain. Unfortunately I cannot find it at this moment. Maybe someone else can find it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This retrieves the part of string that contains #:
`import re
textExample = "5131 + #251 = 76382"
re.findall(r'[^ ]*#[^ ]*',textExample)`

Answer (score 0):

In case the expression does not always separate operators and numbers with spaces, you should search for a preceding or subsequent digit around the pound sign:

```
import re
equation = "5131 + #251 = 76382"
r = re.findall(r"((?<=\d)#|#(?=\d))",equation)
```

If you only intend to replace the pound sign with some digits, you don't need to find/highlight it.  Simply use the built-in string replace function

```
equality = equation.replace("#","71") #==> '5131 + 71251 = 76382'
```